# CSS Clip-path maker in VS Code

Tags: web-apps, web-development, html, css, visual-studio-code

Is there any **VS Code** extension that would help me to make **CSS clip-path** from within the app. I know that there is an online clip-path maker but as I code I rarely leave **VS Code** so an extension would become much handy.